# No content from LWP request

Tags: perl, lwp

**SOLVED: I fixed it by installing HTML::HeadParser.
But I still have no idea why it just suddenly stopped working.**

I noticed some LWP request that have worked before had stopped working so I made a small script to check why.
For some reason I don't get anything back as content from most sites (The only two that have worked so far is icanhazip.com and the gdata.youtube.com api).
I get a status 200 back and I get the right Content-Lenght for the header.
I have tried fetching the page in both curl and wget with no problems. And if I check the requests with tcpdump I do indeed get a reply with all the right information.
I have tried with both LWP::UserAgent and LWP::Simple with the same results.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$agent->agent("Mozilla/5.0");

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://stackoverflow.com');
my $res = $agent->request($req);

print $res->status_line, "\n";
print $res->header("Content-Length"), "\n";
print $res->content, "\n";
```

Dumping $res with DumpLex gives the following:

```
$HTTP_Response1 = bless( {
                    _content => '',
                    _headers => bless( {
                                  "cache-control"
                                               => 'public, max-age=15',
                                  "client-aborted"
                                               => 'die',
                                  "client-date"
                                               => 'Sat, 23 Jun 2012 15:07:23 GMT',
                                  "client-peer"
                                               => '64.34.119.12:80',
                                  "client-response-num"
                                               => 1,
                                  connection   => 'close',
                                  "content-length"
                                               => 211684,
                                  "content-type"
                                               => 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
                                  date         => 'Sat, 23 Jun 2012 15:07:22 ',
                                  expires      => 'Sat, 23 Jun 2012 15:07:38 ',
                                  "last-modified"
                                               => 'Sat, 23 Jun 2012 15:06:38 GMT ',
                                  vary         => '*',
                                  "x-died"     => 'Can\'t locate HTML/HeadParser.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl .) at /usr/share/perl5/site_perl/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 663.'
                                }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                    _msg     => 'OK',
                    _protocol
                             => 'HTTP/1.1',
                    _rc      => 200,
                    _request => bless( {
                                  _content => '',
                                  _headers => bless( {
                                                "content-type" => 'application/html',
                                                "user-agent"   => 'Mozilla/5.0'
                                              }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                                  _method  => 'GET',
                                  _uri     => \do { my $v = 'http://stackoverflow.com/' },
                                  _uri_canonical
                                           => 'V: $HTTP_Response1->{_request}{_uri}'
                                }, 'HTTP::Request' ),
                    default_add_content
                             => 1
                  }, 'HTTP::Response' );
$HTTP_Response1->{_request}{_uri_canonical} = $HTTP_Response1->{_request}{_uri};
bless( $HTTP_Response1->{_request}{_uri}, 'URI::http' );
```

Comment: You say which sites work, but not which don't. How do you determine that you "don't get anything back as content"? Dump a faulty response object: `use Data::Dump::Streamer; DumpLex $res;`

Answer (score 3):

In circumstances like this, when a module seems to be misbehaving beyond its documented functionality, it would be useful to *force* a reinstallation with

```
cpan -f -i LWP::UserAgent
```

and I suggest you do that right now in case there are others problems with your module library.

Comment: That might have worked. Will keep that in mind if I run in to anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

Script you have in your question is working just fine. I bet you have some issues with library.

I suggest you to run

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install LWP::UserAgent'
```

to ensure your library is up-to-date.

Comment: @GraveRaven - I see you just updated your question with **SOLVED: I fixed it by installing HTML::HeadParser.** I believe part of installation of `HTML::HeadParser` was update of `LWP::UserAgent` library, so you updated this library indirectly and that helps. For some unknown reason you had old or damaged library installed on you system, so script didn't exectute as expected. Good luck!

Comment: The odd thing was that just trying to update LWP::UserAgent (One of the first things I tried) resulted in the message LWP::UserAgent is up to date

Comment: @GraveRaven: Why didn't you say so?

Comment: @GraveRaven - Okay guru. Certainly you had some library broken [`HTTP::Request` or `HTTP::Response` or some other(s)], as `HTML::HeadParser` has nothing to do with your code. Anyway. Good luck!

Comment: @simbabque: Mostly because checking if the library I was trying to use was broken and trying to update it seemed like a given.